# Question Marks Instead of Chinese Characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, cjk

I'm trying to place some Chinese text on a website, but as soon as the page is placed online, instead of Chinese text, i see a row of question marks ?????????? ???????????

I tested the same page on a WAMP server before putting it online (all the pages have a php extension) and the Chinese characters show just fine, it is only when the pages are requested from the online host server do i see all the question marks.

the page contains (if this helps):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Check the headers the server's sending. The Content-type header might be overriding your meta tag.

Comment: Check that your Chinese text is encoded in utf-8 before pasting it into your web page. What's the header on the page that works?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with headers, here is the response header from the working page:

Date: Thu, 24 Jun 2010 05:24:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.63 (Win32) PHP/5.2.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11
Content-Length: 3622
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

200 OK

and the non-working page:

Date: Thu, 24 Jun 2010 05:26:54 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.12
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

200 OK

Comment: i would like to add that i only see the question marks when the document has a php extension, however, if i change it to html, the text shows up fine.

Comment: It's possible that your editor isn't saving it as UTF-8 if you save with a .php extension.

Comment: i tried saving it under UTF-8 in notepad with the .php extension, and still no luck. i can see the characters in the source when the file sits on the host server...

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a database of some sort, make sure you run this before querying the database (but after making the connection):

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked for me. Can you explain why this was necessary considering that everything in my database was utf-8 and that my php file was also saved as utf-8?

Comment: @Shawn I'm not exactly sure but my guess would be that the connection depends on the locale of the installation on the remote server, which is not something the developer sets/is usually aware of at dev time.

Comment: For PDO: $dbh->exec("set names utf8");  It was bugging me for 1h and 10min :P

Comment: In PDO, use `charset=utf8` in the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

The actual HTTP response headers will always override the HTML `<meta>` headers. As per your comment:

> I'm not too familiar with headers, here is the response header from the working page:
>
> ```
> Date: Thu, 24 Jun 2010 05:24:23 GMT 
> Server: Apache/2.0.63 (Win32) PHP/5.2.11 
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11 
> Content-Length: 3622 
> Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100 
> Connection: Keep-Alive 
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
> 200 OK
> ```
>
> and the non-working page:
>
> ```
> Date: Thu, 24 Jun 2010 05:26:54 GMT 
> Server: Apache 
> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.12 
> Connection: close 
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
> Content-Type: text/html 
> 200 OK
> ```

See, the HTTP response header of the non-working page has a `Content-Type` of `text/html` **without** any specified charset. It should have been `text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

You can go around this by adding the following line to the **top** of your PHP page, *before* you emit any character (HTML) to the response body.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

---

**Update:** as per the comments, the above cause seems to be excluded. Next check; is the file itself saved as UTF-8? Rightclick page and view source. Are the question marks also there? If so, then something went wrong during FTP transfer to the hosting. Choose binary instead of text/ASCII or set character encoding for transferred text files in FTP client settings and retry.

Comment: Ok, i placed <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?> on the first line of the document, the response header returned Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, however i still only see question marks

Comment: ok, i changed the transfer type to binary, still no luck
i checked the page source, and yes, the question marks are still there. when i check the source of the file in cpanel, i can see the cinese text (so the ftp transfer looks fine)

Comment: Look like a webserver issue. I'd consult the hosting support.

Answer (score 1):

Since the mysql_* functions in PHP are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, here's the SQL that you can execute that essentially does the same as mysql_set_charset:

`SQL
SET character_set_client = utf8`

This was key in getting my forms to save unicode text to MySQL. Execute that SQL query immediately after establishing a connection to your MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to resolve it.

I had the content of the site passing through PHP.  When I viewed it as a raw HTML file, it would display the characters properly, but if I passed it through PHP (in my case, by using auto_prepend_file), it would turn the characters into question marks.

The solution was to turn OFF detect_unicode in the PHP settings.  In my case, I just edited the .htaccess file to include the line:

```
php_value detect_unicode "0"
```

...and the Chinese characters began displaying properly.  There might be an equivalent solution using ini_set().

Hope this helps.