# PHP displaying Chinese characters: SET NAMES 'utf8' not working

Tags: php, utf-8, cjk

I'm trying to work with a database that I have, but I can't display Chinese characters in it. The database was actually a MS Access file first, that I converted into mysql with a program. Anyway, many rows have Chinese characters in them and I can't get them to display properly in any browser.

I can display Chinese characters just fine otherwise, and I can also see them if I use phpmyadmin to look at the tables. I searched around for a solution to this problem and it seems to me that the usual fix is to do the "SET NAMES 'utf8'" query, but this only changed the displayed characters from question marks to other, weird, symbols.

If I look in phpmyadmin collation is utf8_general_ci for the database and all the tables.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how to display precisely chenise characters, but do you use `utf8_encode()` or something?

Comment: Does your php file receives the chars ok? Is it saved in UtF-8 encoding?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front to Back in a Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/). There's quite a few [possible duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107033/question-marks-instead-of-chinese-characters) already answered, please check the sidebar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MySQL DB, this solves the problem:

```
$dbh = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);    
mysql_select_db($db, $dbh);    
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $dbh);
```

PDO solution:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db;charset=UTF-8', $username, $password);
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I get the following error message however:

Warning: mysql_set_charset() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in C:\AppServ\www\hw9\hw9_a.php on line 17

Comment: Vishal: Ok I tried it, but unfortunately still only weird symbols, like these: åœ‹èªž. Any other ideas?

Comment: For me, I added above statement in a common connection file, which I include in almost every file. So now when I insert or update any content (such as unicode chars), then in my db, content with proper utf8 encoding is get saved. Also when I select any of this content from db, it presents it in proper utf8 encoding in html. Just make above `mysql_set_charset()` common to scripts in which your insert/update/select code resides.

Comment: Works! I added this <META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf8"> in the header and also this in the script: mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbh); Thanks guys: SOLVED!

Comment: Using just <meta charset="utf-8"> is enough if you're using new HTML5 DOCTYPE.

Comment: "åœ‹èªž" is UTF-8 "國語" displayed in Windows Latin 1 -- You are having an encoding snafu.

Comment: This is solved my long problem! Thank you very much for PDO solution!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to make sure of a few things:

- Before import, the character set of the table you're going to use has to be set as utf8. You must also make sure the imported data actually contains proper utf8 encoded characters.
- At the time of import you have to specify the character set the established session (e.g. by running `SET NAMES utf8;`)
- After import, you should write a small script that reads a row that you know has special characters in it; the script must:

  - use `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` or whichever mime type you wish to set
  - set the correct character set for the established MySQL connection (utf8)

If all goes well, it should display your data correctly.