# localization in MySql5.0

Tags: mysql, localization

I have created a database using the command:

```
CREATE DATABASE localization CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I have also created a table inside with the command:

```
CREATE TABLE localization(id varchar(20),arabic varchar(20));
```

As the table localization is part of the database localization, it should accept the arabic charactars as well. How do I verify that table localization accepts localized string. When I paste the arabic content on the editor it becomes '?????'. Is there a way to test that the table is accepting arabic strings?

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10674796/1052356) would help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong datatype. For Unicode (which is what you need), you should use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`