# Error when using charset utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

When I use the function `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` I have this error :

> ***Warning: mysql_set_charset() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in D:\wamp\www\plateforme\includes\db.php on line 4***

This is the code :

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=plateforme', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);

?>
```

Comment: mysql and PDO are two different libraries. You can't mix them.

Comment: and to boot you should not be using the mysql_* functions any longer ... use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP displaying Chinese characters: SET NAMES 'utf8' not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674762/php-displaying-chinese-characters-set-names-utf8-not-working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing `mysql_*` and `PDO` , Set the character encoding like this to your existing connection object and remove that `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);` ..

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=plateforme;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ //<--- This.
```